# What's the modern C# way to start two threads and then wait for them to end?

Tags: c#, multithreading

How would you rewrite this using the latest threading techniques in C#?

```
var dateRange = new DateRange(date, date.AddDays(1));
var extracter = new ConversionsExtracter(dateRange, AdvertiserId);
var loader = new ConversionsLoader();
var extracterThread = extracter.Start();
var loaderThread = loader.Start(extracter);
extracterThread.Join();
loaderThread.Join();
```

Both the loader and extract objects have a `Start` method:

```
public  Thread Start()
{
    var thread = new Thread(Extract);
    thread.Start();
    return thread;
}
```

Comment: By "latest threading techniques" are you referring to the `async`/`await` and `Tasks` features in .NET 4.x?

Comment: I believe I am.. I started reading up on it and it's just not completely clear to me if its a drop in replacement for traditional threading or if it only applies in certain circumstances..

Comment: Maybe watch [Easy Asynchrony with C#](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-011) then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With tasks:

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => extracter.Start(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => loader.Start(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

// some arbitrary amount of code here that's executed on the main thread.

// Wait for both threads to complete before continuing.
t1.Wait();
t2.Wait();

// Code here cannot execute until the loader and extractor are finished.
```

Tasks have many features that make them easier to work with than explicitly managing threads, including supporting cancellation, continuations, etc. Well worth looking into.

Comment: That's not right - those are both blocking calls, so the main thread will block until completion.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Yes, the main thread blocks until both threads are done. It's an exact duplicate of the behavior that the OP showed, just using `Task`. I assumed that he simplified things by eliminating the processing that the main thread does while these two threads are doing there thing. There could be any amount of stuff happening before the first call to `Wait`, but then the main thread has to make sure the other threads are done before it can move on. Perhaps my edit gives you a better idea?

Comment: I would prefer `Task.WhenAll(t1, t2).Wait()`, which will allow catching exceptions from _both_ of the Tasks if `t1` throws. It may also be trivially less expensive due to creating only a single synchronization object to block on rather than two.

Comment: If you're blocking anyway, I'd say `Task.WaitAll(t1, t2)`. Also, you should either use `Task.Run` or explicitly pass a scheduler to `StartNew`.

Answer (score 0):

Using this defined method:

```
async Task<TResult> RunLoadAsync(/* args */) {
  var dateRange = new DateRange(date, date.AddDays(1));
  var extracter = new ConversionsExtracter(dateRange, AdvertiserId);
  var loader    = new ConversionsLoader();

  var intermediate = await Task.Factory.StartNew(
      () => extracter.Start(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
  );
  return await Task.Factory.StartNew(
      () => loader.Start(intermediate), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
  );
}
```

invoke it like this:

```
   var result = await RunLoadAsync(/* parameters */);
```

**Update**: Here is a more complete example of usage:

```
private async void PanelBoard_MouseCtlClick(object sender, HexEventArgs e) {
  GoalHex = e.Coords;
  // other processing to prepare.
  try { Path = await MapBoard.GetDirectedPathAsync(MapBoard[StartHex], MapBoard[GoalHex]); } 
  catch (OperationCanceledException) { Path = default(IDirectedPath); }
}

public static async Task<IDirectedPath> GetDirectedPathAsync(
  this IBoard<IHex> @this, 
  IHex start,  IHex goal
) {
  if (@this == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("this");
  return @this.GetDirectedPath(start, goal);
}

IDirectedPath Path {
  set { /* code here to refresh display when Path is ready */ }
}

public static Task<IDirectedPath> GetDirectedPathAsync(
  this IBoard<IHex> @this, 
  IHex start,  IHex goal
) {
  if (@this == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("this");
  return Task.Run<IDirectedPath>(
      () => @this.GetDirectedPath(start, goal)
  );
}
```

The **async** qualifier on the method **GetDirectedPathAsync()** enables it to be the object of **await**.

Comment: `RunLoadAsync` will complete synchronously here. Merely putting in an `async` keyword does not create concurrency.

Comment: @CoryNelson: Which is why it is **invoked** asynchronously using the *await* keyword, as illustrated above.

Comment: `RunLoadAsync()` will block and return a fully completed task. Then the `await` will complete immediately. It's literally as if you just called `RunLoad()` directly, but have added a lot of overhead for absolutely no change in behavior -- no asynchrony here.

Comment: To explain:

`async` methods are 100% synchronous (i.e. they execute in the same thread as the caller) and do not return a `Task` until they hit an `await`. Until you use `await` in `RunLoadAsync`, there is absolutely no change other than the result of your method will be wrapped in a `Task`.

`await` does not invoke something asynchronously. The `await` happens _after_ the method is called. It is the callee's (`RunLoadAsync`) job to introduce asynchrony, and the caller's job (with `await`) to wait for that (possibly asynchronous, possibly not) `Task` to complete.

Comment: @CoryNelson: Thank you! That was more informative than several dozen pages of MSDN. I was fooled by the speed of my path-finding.

Comment: @CoryNelson: How is this now?

Comment: Much better. See also `Task.Run` for short-lived tasks. It is more efficient than `Task.Factory.StartNew`, but doesn't offer the ability to hint that it'll be long-running.

Comment: Ah! Task.Run will be perfect for my PathFinding, since it runs so quickly! Thanks again.